# Formik select box not updating field on form submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, formik

I am using Formik with React to handle my web application forms.

When I try to submit any form with a  field it does not include the right selected value for that field, it assumes the default value.

In the case bellow the  element corresponds to the input "clientId", when I pick a client and then submit the form, Formik assumes always the clientId as the empty string (the default value).

I tried to replace my dynamic select box with the following code from the docs

```
<Field name="color" component="select" placeholder="Favorite Color">
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</Field>
```

but yet, it did not work.

Is there any problem with my code? Is this a bug in the version I am using?

I tried to find any issues on github related to this problem but I could not find anything.

Here is my formik form:

```
<Formik
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            initialValues={{clientId: '', invoice_number: '', date: '', products: []}}
            render={({
                         values,
                         errors,
                         status,
                         touched,
                         handleBlur,
                         handleChange,
                         handleSubmit,
                         isSubmitting,
                     }) => (
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

                    <SelectClientInput
                        name={"clientId"}
                    />


                    <br/>

                    <input
                        placeholder="Número da fatura"
                        type="text"
                        name="invoice_number"
                        className={"form-control"}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                        value={values.invoice_number}
                    />

                    <br/>

                    <input
                        placeholder="Data"
                        type="date"
                        name="date"
                        className={"form-control"}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                        value={values.date}
                    />



                    <br/>


                    <button type="submit" className={"btn btn-success"} disabled={isSubmitting}>
                        Criar produto
                    </button>
                </form>
            )}
        />)
```

and this SelectClientInput component

```
class SelectClientInput extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            clients: [],
        }
    }

    componentWillMount = () => {
        this.searchClients();
    }

    searchClients = (inputValue = "") => {
        var self = this;
        //Search tax payers
        axios.get('/api/clients')
            .then(function (response) {
                var clients = response.data.clients;
                self.setState({clients: clients});
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    render = () => {
        return (
            <Field
                component="select"
                name={this.props.name}
                className={'form-control'}
            >
                {(this.state.clients && this.state.clients.length > 0) ?
                    this.state.clients.map((client) => {
                        return (<option key={client.id} value={client.id}>{client.name}</option>);
                    }) : (<option key={1}>Nenhum cliente encontrado</option>)
                }
            </Field>
        );
    }
};
```

I am using react-dom 16.6 and formik 1.3.1

Note: Every field is sent with the right value except form the  fields.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an 'connection' between controls/fields and formik's `values`.

Their state/value needs to be saved in `values` as it's done using `handleChange` for inputs.

`<Field />` needs to be placed inside `<Form />` component, not simple html `<form />`.

`<SelectClientInput />` is a component, it needs a separate change handler (updating Formik `values` using `setValues`) passed in as prop. Actual value (`values.clientId`) should be passed as prop, too. It's standard raact [lifting state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) technique.